# How to use UK-format date in linq with operators

Tags: linq

i have got a big problem with converting dates in c#,i want to query using LINQ,in my condition i have to put date,if i put DateTime its in american format and database which expecting UK format does not recognize the date,if use ToString('dd,MM,yyyy') to get british format,i cant use string in LINQ condition,what should i do?

```
      var rslt=(from t in cr.table1
                  join v in cr.errorCatGroup
                  on  t.m_error_id equals v.m_error_id
                  where t.m_date >= myDateTime1 && t.m_date <= myDateTime2 
                  select new  {
                      GroupName=t.Error
                  }).ToList();
```

i get mDateTime1 and myDateTime2 like :

```
        CultureInfo ukCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        DateTime myDateTime1 = DateTime.Parse("30/09/2018", ukCulture.DateTimeFormat);
        DateTime result12 = DateTime.ParseExact("01-10-2018", "d-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

so whats the right way of using it in LINQ

Comment: Why does the database even **have** a format? `DateTime` does not have a format at all, you can specify a format and a culture when you convert it to a string, but the `DateTime` value itself does not have a format. Are the dates stored as text in the database? If so, when you say american and UK format, what specifically is the format?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen in Postgres its DATE,you mean when i get the date from user,which is string i need to comvert it to the date and then query?without caring about the format,right?

Comment: If the type in the database is `DATE` then you should absolutely pass in the values as `DateTime` in your LINQ query. Since you're asking "so what's the right way of using it in LINQ", may I ask what didn't work when you tried what you did? In other words, it seems to me that you're on the right track, what makes you think you aren't?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i thought the DB is expecting to get the same format ,by putting a break point i say the format im sending is american even thought i put GB there,now its cleared to me that when i send the date i should not matter the format,since the other end is expecting DATE,thanks a lot

Comment: Again, `DateTime` does not have a format, whatever format you're seeing is the debugger being helpful and showing the result of calling `.ToString()` without any culture, which is likely to be your current computer culture. This is completely unrelated to what you're sending to the database, which is more like a pure number without any format whatsoever.